# Какой алгоритм перемещения? JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вам необходимо создать приложение для автоматизации работы погрузочных кранов,
позволяющих перемещать плиты между грузовыми автомобилями на крупной
строительной площадке.
Приложение должно предоставлять кранам последовательность разгрузки, оптимальную
для переноса груза с автомобиля на автомобиль, учитывая следующее:

● плиты размещаются на автомобилях одна над другой (от 3 до 8 штук в высоту), и
отсортированы по весу (от тяжелых - снизу, к легким - сверху)

● кран может снимать и перемещать только самую верхнюю плиту с грузовика, и при
разгрузке не может устанавливать более тяжелые плиты на более легкие

● перенос груза с загруженного автомобиля на пустой нужно осуществить используя
только одно дополнительное место для временного хранения плит

Входящие параметры:
Количество плит на автомобиле, который требуется разгрузить (от 3 до 8)

```
Пример:
[3,2,1]
[]      
[]
---
[3,2]
[]
[1]
---
[3]
[2]
[1]
---
[3]
[2,1]
[]
---
[]
[21]
[3]
---
[1]
[2]
[3]
---
[1]
[]
[3,2]
---
[]
[]
[3,2,1]
```

Не могу найти правильный алгоритм перемещения

Comment: _Вам необходимо создать приложение_ - ну дак дерзайте!

Answer (score 1):

Решайте по аналогии с ханойскими башнями.

Вот блок-схема решения данной задачи рекурсивным методом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Существует несколько подходов к решению, все они дают идентичные результаты.

**Рекурсивное решение**

Рекурсивно решаем задачу «перенести башню из n−1 диска на 2-й штырь». Затем переносим самый большой диск на 3-й штырь, и рекурсивно решаем задачу «перенеси башню из n−1 диска на 3-й штырь».

Отсюда методом математической индукции заключаем, что минимальное число ходов, необходимое для решения головоломки, равно 2n − 1, где n — число дисков[2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)[3].

В информатике задачи, основанные на легенде о Ханойской башне, часто рассматривают в качестве примера использования рекурсивных алгоритмов и преобразования их к нерекурсивным.

**«Треугольное» решение**

Расположим штыри в виде треугольника. Начнём с самого маленького кольца и переложим его на любую отметку.

В дальнейшем это кольцо нужно перемещать в том же направлении, что и при первом перекладывании.

Затем перенесём какое-нибудь из оставшихся колец (такой ход единственный), после чего снова переложим самое маленькое кольцо и т. д.

(Интересно заметить, что перенумеровав «кольца» по порядку, мы добьёмся неожиданного эффекта: чётные кольца будут перемещаться из одной вершины треугольника в другую в одном направлении, а нечётные — в противоположном направлении.)

**Циклическое решение**

Обозначим через «1-2» такое действие: переложить диск или с 1-го штыря на 2-й, или со 2-го на 1-й, в зависимости от того, где он меньше.

Тогда, чтобы решить головоломку с чётным количеством дисков, надо многократно повторять действия: 1-2, 1-3, 2-3. Если число дисков нечётно — 1-3, 1-2, 2-3.

[Ссылка на описание решения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Cпасибо, разобрался

Comment: @Denis, всегда пожалуйста.